# Any way to include variable date in API URL?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python, I have been able to connect to an API and get the data I want. However I notice that the date field has be hardcoded in the URL.

```
https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/rto/fuel-type-data/data?api_key=XXXX&start=2022-05-18T00
```

I plan to run the script daily and I am only interested in the past week of data. Is there a way to code this so I don't need to change the date manually everyday?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to get the current date, how to format it or how to format something into a URL?

Comment: Could you also show the code that's making the request?